# Azure Synapse Analytics Error when using saveAsTable from a DataFrame which is loaded from a SQL source

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm following the guide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/get-started) for loading data from a SQL Pool and writing the DataFrame to a table in the metastore.  However I'm getting an error:

Error : org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.contracts.exceptions.AbfsRestOperationException: Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.", 403, PUT, https://xxx.dfs.core.windows.net/tempdata/synapse/workspaces/xxx/sparkpools/SparkPool/sparkpoolinstances/8f3ec14a-1e59-4597-8fd9-42da0db65331?action=setAccessControl&timeout=90, AuthorizationPermissionMismatch, "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission. RequestId:fe61799c-e01f-0003-119e-37fdb1000000 Time:2020-05-31T22:57:55.8271281Z"

I've replaced my resource names with xxx.

Other DataFrame saveAsTable operations work fine.  From what I can see, the data is being read from the SQL Pool successfully and being staged as when I browse the data lake location specified in the error I can see the data.

/tempdata/synapse/workspaces/xxx/sparkpools/SparkPool/sparkpoolinstances/8f3ec14a-1e59-4597-8fd9-42da0db65331

The Synapse workspace managed identity has storage blob data contributor permissions and my own domain account has owner access.

Has anyone else had issues?

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Please assign yourself (account with which you're trying to run the script) a role of **Storage Blob Data Contributor**. 
Below information is **now** showing up during the creation of Azure Synapse workspace. 
[image]
*It was a big struggle to figure this out during it's private preview.* 
More information related to securing synapse workspace can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/security/how-to-set-up-access-control). 
Let me know if this worked.
Thank you.